# Tor Browser Mac OSX 10.11.2

Tags: mac, tor-browser-bundle

I have downloaded the Tor Browser, mounted the .dmg file, copied the application to the application folder (as well as the desktop and a thumb-drive on subsequent efforts) and am able to launch the application without error.  However, once open I am faced with a screen describing connection options.  My internet connection is not censored or proxied and should not require a bridge for connection.  When choosing "Connect" to establish a direct connection to the Tor network the entire application immediately closes. No window pops up to indicate a connection is being attempted, and no browser ever appears.  Activity monitor shows no activity associated with the Tor browser.

I have removed and reinstalled to various locations.
I have redownloaded from project tor.
I have turned off my firewall entirely (and then back on) to no avail.
I have attempted to configure a bridge (despite other local devices being able to connect to Tor without issue).

No matter what I do upon any effort to connect Tor Browser application closes immediately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to use the terminal? If so, could you try starting the application from there (on the command line)? This would hopefully provide some form of logging...